# range based for loop that ignores elements

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a unit test for a custom container type.  I want to make sure it contains the right number of elements.

```
int count = 0;
for (const auto &el : region) {
  ++count;
}
// Check that count is the right number
```

Because this code does not do anything with 'el', I get a compiler warning about an unused variable.  How can one write a range-based for loop without declaring a "variable alias" like 'el'?

An old-fashioned for-loop that explicitly uses iterators would obviously solve this problem, but I'm just curious to know if it can be done with range-based for.

Comment: You have to declare it. The least you can do to "ignore" it is `(void)el`.

Comment: `region` doesn't have a `size` member that would tell you how big it is?

Comment: `const auto count = std::distance(std::begin(region), std::end(region));` ?

Comment: I've used a `NumRange` class which lets you do, for instance, `for (size_t i : mk_NumRange(n_iterations)) { /* whatever */ }`.  It's great if `i` is used, but if you just want to repeat something `n_iterations` times, ignoring `i` useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two ways to suppress the warning:

```
for ([[maybe_unused]] const auto &el : region) // C++17 or newer
{
    // ...
}
```

or

```
for (const auto &el : region)
{
    (void)el;
    // ...
}
```

---

But as noted in comments by @Jarod42, you could just use `std::distance(std::begin(region), std::end(region));` instead, if your container has proper iterators.

Comment: Casting to `void` might not suppress warning for some compilers, even if it suppress warning on major ones.